# Remove contents between parentheses in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, ecmascript-6

Create a function that accepts a string as input, removes all content between parentheses, and returns the modified string. If the amount of left and right parentheses doesn't match, return empty string

I have to create a function that removes all content between parentheses and returns the string without it.

For example, this input **12(3(45))67(8)9** will return this output **12679**.

If the number of parentheses isn't correct return an empty string.

This is my approach:

```
function removeContent(str) {
  let leftP = 0, rightP = 0;
  // wrong number of parentheses scenario
  for( let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if(str[i] === '(' ) leftP++;
    if(str[i] === ')' ) rightP++;
  }
  if( leftP !== rightP) return "";
  
  // remove the content otherwise
}

console.log(removeContent('12(3(45))67(8)9'));
```

Don't know how to do the combination between pairing parentheses and remove the content.

Comment: Add an `int` that counts the number of unclosed parentheses sections in your `for` loop (+1 for `(`, -1 for `)`). When this value equals 0, you add a character to the returning string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to do this is to keep track of bracket count, and then output letters only when the bracket count is equal to 0.

At the end, if the bracket count is not zero, you can also tell it to return the empty string as requested..

eg..

```js
function removeContent(string) {
  let bracketCount = 0;
  let output = '';
  for (const letter of string) {
    if (letter === '(') bracketCount += 1
    else if (letter === ')') bracketCount -= 1
    else if (bracketCount === 0) output += letter;
  }
  return bracketCount === 0 ? output : '';
}


console.log(removeContent('12(3(45))67(8)9'));
console.log(removeContent('12(345))67(8)9'));
console.log(removeContent('1(2)(3)45(7)8(((9)))77'));
```

Answer (score -1):

do a find replace with regular expression `/\(+[\d\(]*\)+/g`

Comment: Does not seem to work for the given example.

Comment: I pasted the examples in regXR and it seemed to work

Comment: Well, I don't know how you manage to do it but for `12(3(45))67(8)9`, I get `(45))`.

Comment: oh, my bad dude, looks like there's some edge cases to work out but honestly if you can nail down a good regex to use this problem will be a two liner

Comment: give this a try `/[\(\d][\d\(\)]*[\)\d]/g`

Comment: wait a minute don't use that, forgot the scope of the problem, we're looking for numbers within parenthesis

Comment: `\({1,}[\d\(\)]*\)` except somehow make it reject 6 and 7 from the following sequence (3(45))67(8)